# How do I get non-parametric test values (not just p) in PASW 18?

Tags: nonparametric, spss

from what I can tell, PASW v.18 (the new version of SPSS) only gives you the p value of nonparametric tests. I am calculating Kruskal Wallis and Mann Whitney tests, and need to report the test statistic, not just p. Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click the output to obtain the test statistics box.

Comment: could you show a screen shot of what the output looks like before and after this step?

Answer (score 4):

PASW 18 does give you the test statistic in addition to the p value.

For example, if you have selected Mann Whitney test, the output from SPSS will include a Test Statistics box that shows the mann Whitney U statistic

The same thing applies for the Kruskal Wallis test, although note that SPSS labels the statistic Chi-Square, rather than H.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I was looking everywhere for an option to select, but I see you need to double click on the output and a model viewer comes up with the information. Thanks.